# Getting error "Method invocation failed because [System.Net.IPAddress[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Where""

Tags: powershell

My script to get ipaddress from hostname gets this error when running on windows 7 computers. Any workaround possibly. Im assuming its caused by not having updated powershell, but it is not feasible for me to update all computers powershells.
my code looks like

```
if ($tech_name -eq "brian" -or $tech_name -eq "6" ){    
    $wshell.SendKeys([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("XXXXXX").where({$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'}).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In earlier versions of PowerShell you can use the where-object cmdlet instead, but then you need some more parens to get the property.

```
$wshell.SendKeys(([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("XXXXXX") | where-object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'}).IPAddressToString)
$wshell.SendKeys("~")
```